# print array of characters as 64 bit integer

Tags: c, char, integer

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char val[8] = { 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88 };
    printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long int *) (&val[0]));
}
```

I am trying to print an array of 8 byte * 8 as a 64 bit integer but getting some junk values. Can someone help.

Comment: You are converting to a pointer. Why?

Comment: Note: an `unsigned long long int` is not necessarily 64 bits.  It could be longer.  Better to use `uint64_t`.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing what is the use of (unsigned long long int *) in my statement ?. I mean what does this signify does it inform the printf function that the address is pointing to 64 bit integer ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way around.

It should be something like:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

printf("%" PRIu64, *(uint64_t *) val);
```

You want to dereference ("follow") the pointer to the first byte interpreted as a pointer to a 64-bit integer, to get a 64-bit integer to pass to `printf()`.

Note that `&val[0]` is the same thing as `val` in this context, so why not keep it simple.

Comment: Minor: Suggest `"%" PRIx64 "\n"` in keeping with OP's `printf()`.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing what is the use of (unsigned long long int *)  in my statement ?. I mean what does this signify does it inform the printf function that the address is pointing to 64 bit integer ?.

Comment: @chaitanyavarma Your code doesn't do what you want, so it's a bit hard to reason about it *as if it did*. The cast in your code converts the address of an `unsigned char` into the address of an `unsigned long`, and tells `printf()` to expect an `unsigned long` *value*. **Not** an address. It causes undefined behavior through this mis-match. Never lie to `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
printf("%llx\n", *((unsigned long long int *) (&val[0])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you print value of address (pointer).

You should dereference variable before print:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
main ()
{
    uint8_t val [8] = {0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88};
    printf ("%llx\n", * (uint64_t *) (val) );
}
```

As suggested by **chux** it's better use explicit types with guaranteed size.

Additionally, name of array is pointer of it's first element, so you can simplify code and use:

```
val
```

instead of:

```
&val[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working missing the basic pointer arthmatic.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char val[8] = { 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88 };
    printf("%llx\n", *(unsigned long long int *) (&val[0]));
}
```